# call Live wallpaper within application

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am trying to implement following thing in android 2.x.

[image]

In my application i want to allow the user to create the custom live wallpaper kind of thing where 
user chooses few images and then those image will rotate in a typical fashion and after that user will be able to set it all the view as a live wallpaper within the application only.

i have successfully implemented the selection of images and its rotation now i don't know how to set live wallpaper within the application. i have tried implementing  Live Wallpaper chooser but it is used to access already installed live wallpaper. but what about the dynamically created live wallpaper?

Even i tried to call it using following line of code

```
intent.setClassName("com.android.wallpaper.livepicker", "com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperPreview");
```

But it is giving me an error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/.LiveWallpaperPreview } from ProcessRecord{43f94a38 29784:com.vb.ui/10038} (pid=29784, uid=10038) requires null
```

**There might be few ways but m not sure about it**

is it possible to install live wallpaper apk programmatically  so that once the live wallpaper is created it is being installed by the application ?

if live wallpapers are stored in some place then we can store user created live wallpaper at that place so when live wallpaper chooser is being selected we can see the live wallpaper in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should open this custom picking activity from within the standard "Settings" button a user sees when choosing your live wallpaper.

1. User goes into standard live wallpaper chooser, sees a list of installed LWPs, picks yours.
2. User sees your default implementation, chooses "Settings" button.
3. You show a list of settings, one of which is a `PreferenceScreen` named "Pick Images."
4. Assign an `onClickListener` to that preference item which launches your custom image picking activity.